Unexpected Delay with conn.Read in Go TCP Server
I'm experiencing an unexpected delay when using conn.Read in a simple Go TCP server. The delay occurs when reading commands from the connection, even though the commands are sent immediately. I connect using telnet but I have also tried to send the commands programmatically.
I have a simple Go TCP server that listens for connections and processes SET and GET commands. The server works as expected when run locally or on the same network, but when I run it on a remote server, I encounter a significant delay (about 17 seconds) when reading GET commands from the client. Specifically, and here is the odd thing, is that if I send/write the GET command using a space at the end there is no delay.

If I write this (without the quotes) and hit enter I have a large
delay around ~13-20 seconds: "GET mykey"
If I write the same (without the
quotes) with a space at the end, it works without any delay "GET
mykey "

More strange is that after the first command, either it delayed or not, all the other commands work without delay.
I have identified that the delay is happening on the conn.Read. I used also a bufio.Reader and bufio.NewScanner but I get the same behavior.
What could be causing this delay in conn.Read when running the server remotely, and how can I resolve it?
The code:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Store struct {
    mu    sync.RWMutex
    store map[string]string
}

func NewStore() *Store {
    return &Store{
        store: make(map[string]string),
    }
}

func (s *Store) Set(key, value string) {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    s.store[key] = value
}

func (s *Store) Get(key string) (string, bool) {
    s.mu.RLock()
    defer s.mu.RUnlock()
    value, ok := s.store[key]
    return value, ok
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn, store *Store) {
    defer conn.Close()
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

    for {
        //conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second))

        startRead := time.Now()
        input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        readDuration := time.Since(startRead)
        fmt.Println("Read duration:", readDuration)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Connection closed or read error:", err)
            return
        }

        input = strings.TrimSpace(input)
        parts := strings.SplitN(input, " ", 3)

        if len(parts) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        command := parts[0]
        switch command {
        case "SET":
            if len(parts) != 3 {
                fmt.Fprintln(writer, "ERROR: Usage: SET <key> <value>")
                writer.Flush()
                continue
            }
            key := parts[1]
            value := parts[2]
            store.Set(key, value)
            fmt.Fprintln(writer, "OK")
            writer.Flush()

        case "GET":
            if len(parts) != 2 {
                fmt.Fprintln(writer, "ERROR: Usage: GET <key>")
                writer.Flush()
                continue
            }
            key := parts[1]
            value, ok := store.Get(key)
            if !ok {
                fmt.Fprintln(writer, "ERROR: Key not found")
            } else {
                fmt.Fprintln(writer, value)
            }
            writer.Flush()

        default:
            fmt.Fprintln(writer, "ERROR: Unknown command")
            writer.Flush()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    store := NewStore()
    port := ":12345"

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error starting server:", err)
        return
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    fmt.Println("Server started on port", port)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            continue
        }

        go handleConnection(conn, store)
    }
}


Update:
I discovered that the issue was most likely caused by Middleware or Proxy Servers. I replaced the GET with any other name and the issue stopped. I added also tls connection between the client and the server and the GET works without delays.
